# access with vino without ask me permissions

Tags: vnc, vino

i have ubuntu 12.10. how I can access my computer remotely with vino, without ask me permissions on the server? I need something like LogMeIn, or how i can stop vino asking me for permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Open vino preferences by executing:

```
user@host:~$ vino-preferences
```

And clear the selection beside "You must confirm each access to this machine".